# Styling ForbiddenHttpException error in yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

When I get a `ForbiddenHttpException` its just ugly black on white text. It's not using the standard pretty Yii2 error from the 'views/site/error.php'

> An Error occurred while handling another error: exception
>   'yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException' with message 'You are not allowed to
>   perform this action.' in
>   /vendor/yiisoft/yii2/filters/AccessControl.php:151

Config has:

```
'errorHandler' => [
    'errorAction' => 'site/error',
],
```

Is it possible to style ALL Yii2 errors to look the same?

Comment: Show us your SiteController behaviors (you should simply allow error action)

Comment: you are right @soju i wasn't allowing `error` for authenticated users...

Comment: @soju please put that in an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check for errorHandler in you main config

```
'errorHandler' => [
        'errorAction' => 'site/error',
    ],
```

If it is not there it will show u a plain text.
And for Access Control Custom Error handling you can set a denyCallback in access behaviour

```
'denyCallback' => function($rule, $action){
               // Your Code Goes Here
            }
```

Comment: Can i set global forbiddenExceptoin for whole application?

Comment: override the error action,create a custom error action and set what ever you want.